# Aptana 3 becomes very sluggish with multiple (large) projects, how do I improve performance?

Tags: ide, aptana, aptana3

Aptana 3 becomes very sluggish with multiple (large) projects, how do I improve performance?

I have several projects that I checkout of subversion into a dev directory that I can access through Apache as well. Something like this

So if I go to this URL http://local.dev I can see all the project folders. In Aptana it looks like this

```
+ dev (main project folder that Apache uses as well)
 - project (svn branch I'm currently testing)
 - another_project (another svn branch)
 - yet_another_project (yep, another svn branch)
```

So to access the project form the URL I don't need to configure Apache every time, I just need to access the project folder like this http://local.dev/project or http://local.dev/another_project

The problem is these project are very large (Prado, Zend and Drupal frameworks as well as additional Libraries as needed) and I could have multiple branches of the same project checked out into different folders. Aptana indexes all of this which is what I think the problem is. I know I could create a project for each of these within Aptana itself and close the project if I'm not using it but I don't see the option to do this to a folder within the project (which I think should solve my problem), but if I do separate project folders that I also need to setup Apache to point to the new location, which is another pain in itself.

Is there a way to close a sub-folder in a project folder in Aptana? or have a sub-project folder? or Close a folder within a project? or exclude indexing of a folder? or turn off indexing?

NOTE: Sometimes when adding a new folder within a project I get the out of memory warning and/or Aptana crashes. Also when coding Aptana becomes so sluggish that it's very cumbersome to do anything at all. I really love the Aptana IDE but this might be a deal breaker for me.

I was thinking I would move the Apache site to the Aptana root directory so I could access it on a project level but I don't think this will work for the indexing performance on the Aptana side of things.

UPDATE:
This might be related:

- http://jira.appcelerator.org/secure/EditComment!default.jspa?id=75032&commentId=169647

Looks like Aptana is indexing the .svn folders

UPDATE:

So far the only thing to help is to make a new workspace for each project I need to checkout of svn. This is a pain to switch back and forth between projects but Aptana is usable again.

UPDATE #2

- http://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-1706

Looks like this made the Aptana BUG list, Yeah!

UPDATE #3

After countless tinkering to get Aptana to play nice I decided to test other IDE's.

Started with Eclipse as that's what Aptana is based from. I have a nice build going but it's still not 100% what I was looking for.

Also trying PHPStorm which is paid IDE but I'm finding it's a top notch IDE

Comment: Indexing is supposed to improve performance, but I can see how it'll backfire sometimes.

Comment: @BoltClock I agree but it's not in my case

Answer (score 5):

You could right-click on the project or folder and select **Indexing** > **Exclude from index** to disable indexing on the specific selection.

You could also turn off **Project** > **Build Automatically** from the main menu so the build doesn't get triggered on the project each time a file in it is saved.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for the Indexing -> Exclude I will have to try this and post back the results. As for the Project -> Auto Build, this is not set for any project I have

Comment: sorry this did not help me. I went through all the projects except the one I was working on and excluded from index, this caused a bigger problem on restarting Aptana. During the shutdown process it wanted to rebuild every project I had excluded causing massive memory errors, warnings and the dreaded fade to gray screen. I have to kill -9/force quit Aptana and am now back to square one. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I've been having the same problem myself and found going to 'Project' > 'Clean...' helped significantly, although it took a while to run.

Answer (score 1):

I keep my projects in separate workspaces, I use ramdisk for the entire workspace and aptana. And i also disable indexing for folders with compiled libraries or stuff aptana can't even index anyway.

I use AMD ramdisk paid version. With the free version you have to make sure you do constant commits in the event of a power loss. THe cost of performance.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I just moved off Coda on the Mac over to Aptana 3 so I could have code intellisense and some more validators. But their JSLint is working all backwards, and now recently I have projects with 1000+ lines of code and they can barely scroll.  Sometimes I can barely highlight text.  Often I'll highlight a whole section so I can indent and it just removes the code if my mouse isn't in the right spot.  I originally had this performance with Eclipse when I tried it out and abandoned it since it was so slow.  My assumption here since I've got a 4.2Ghz i7 980X w/ 12GB of RAM and RAID'd SSD Drives - the bottle neck isn't the system.

Comment: Yeah I'm still having issues with Aptana 3 and looking for an alternative that's cross platform (Mac, Win & Linux)

Comment: Starting to consider Komodo or Webstorm.  Tough to find one with a nice balance of intellisense, error/warning integration and validation feedback.  Webstorm seems to have some added features to let you reduce some code when you have to much in your if/else conditions etc ...  To a point now where I notice I can't even copy and paste without having to hit CMD+C like 10 times.

Comment: Just tried Coda... MUCH better than Aptana :) Much much much better

Answer (score 0):

totally agree... the bare-metal eclipse is doing better than Aptana... but i guess it gonna stall on large files and projets (like my todo list with 14.000 lines html file)

i gave more ram to aptana by modifying the config... but it's still sluggish (i5, 4GB of RAM, SSD)

the Clean-Option is greyed out (i am using only "General" Projects)

C'MON IBM YOU CAN DO BETTER :)

Comment: it'sAptana Studio 3, build: 3.6.1.201410201044
(c) Copyright 2005-2013 by Appcelerator, Inc. All rights reserved.

Aptana Studio is licensed under the terms of the GNU Public License (GPL) v3 (with exceptions). Please visit http://www.aptana.com/legal/ for more information.

To view additional credits and copyrights, please view the credits page in the Aptana Studio 3 help system.

Our privacy policy is located at http://www.aptana.com/privacy_policy

Build: jenkins-studio3-rcp-master-87 (origin/master)
Date: 20 October 2014, 10:45:27

Comment: AptanaStudio3.ini 
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.v20140116-2212
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
1024m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-name
Aptana Studio 3
-vmargs
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m
-Xverify:none
-Declipse.p2.unsignedPolicy=allow
-Declipse.log.size.max=10000
-Declipse.log.backup.max=5
-Djava.awt.headless=true

Comment: Linux DebianGiada 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt7-1 (2015-03-01) x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: THE WORKST BUG is the "wrong rendering of text" BUG.

https://youtu.be/dcgaeQJy12M

Answer (score 0):

Right Click project folder and click "**Close Unrelated Projects**". Because Aptana live time index all opened project's folders.